# QueueExistsAsync is not working in WebApi

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I have successfully executed `managementClient.QueueExistsAsync(_queueName)` function in the console application.However, when I try to implement the same code in the WebApi, `managementClient.QueueExistsAsync(_queueName)` the function remains stuck for an indefinite time.

I want to create the azure bus service queue pro-grammatically; therefore, I have to check whether it exits or not?

```
static async Task<IQueueClient> GetOrCreateQueue(string _serviceBusConnectionString, string _queueName)
        {
            var managementClient = new ManagementClient(_serviceBusConnectionString);
            if (!(await managementClient.QueueExistsAsync(_queueName)))
            {
                await managementClient.CreateQueueAsync(

                    new QueueDescription(_queueName)
                    {
                        LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
                    }
                );
            }

            return new QueueClient(_serviceBusConnectionString, _queueName);
        }
```

Comment: Are you passing the correct value for the connection string? And can you confirm it by making sure you can create a queue (passing some random name that you can delete) and sending a message to it?

Comment: You aren't by chance invoking this method from a non-async bootstrapping method, like so: `YourStaticClass.GetOrCreateQueue(...).Wait()`. This might be a deadlock.

Comment: Yes i am sure; as i mentioned earlier, the connection strings and the queue name both are same in the console application and the WebAPi.

Comment: Can you provide more information about WebApi? Is it .NET Core or Framework? Do you invoke it from a controller? If so, what's the controller snippet. The management client method works, so it's not ASB library, but the WebAPI implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What you are likely running into is a deadlock issue between your QueueClient and your WebAPI controller. There is a great explanation [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), but essentially the QueueClient can't return the data because it waiting for the same thread to open up that WebAPI has blocked. Console apps don't have this issue because they don't have anything running asynchronously other than what you specify.

You either need to make your Service Bus calls synchronous or make sure that all the method calls in the stack are async so that you don't hit this deadlock.

If you share your controller code I help to confirm this is the problem and help modify your code to solve it.